# Magento 2 :- how to get the subcategories from main category url

Tags: magento2, category, blocks

I want to get the subcategories of a main category using main category url.

I tried in this way in a **function in my block**.

```
$category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$url_key);
```

[image]
but i cannot get any thing.

Comment: ensure your url-key is not a complete url, it should be something like 'furniture' and not http://www.example.com/furniture.html

Comment: please check the updated question again

Comment: try this $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$url_key)->getFirstItem();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Category

```
$categoryCollection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()      
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$url_key)->getFirstItem(); 

$childs = $categoryCollection->getChildrenCategories();
foreach ($childs as  $child) {
   echo $child->getUrlKey();
}
```